# 16x2 LCD text not showing up on Pico W

Tags: i2c, pi-pico, lcd

I have been using an online tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8Kr_3xHjqE&t=166s, to display text on a LCD. The LCD can do all the functions except the displaying of text. I know there is a similar issue like this but on the Zero, but this is a microcontroller, not a minicomputer. But, how am I supposed to display the text? Please write your answer in simple beginner terms and explain deeply, as I just got my Pico a few days ago and am completely new to it.

The code for displaying the text:

`def test_main():
    #Test function for verifying basic functionality
    print("Running test_main")
    i2c = I2C(0, sda=machine.Pin(0), scl=machine.Pin(1), freq=400000)
    lcd = I2cLcd(i2c, I2C_ADDR, I2C_NUM_ROWS, I2C_NUM_COLS)
    print("Attempting to print It works")
    lcd.putstr("It Works!")
    utime.sleep(2)
    lcd.clear()
    count = 0
    while True:
        lcd.clear()
        time = utime.localtime()
        lcd.putstr("{year:>04d}/{month:>02d}/{day:>02d} {HH:>02d}:{MM:>02d}:{SS:>02d}".format(
            year=time[0], month=time[1], day=time[2],
            HH=time[3], MM=time[4], SS=time[5]))
        if count % 10 == 0:
            print("Turning cursor on")
            lcd.show_cursor()
        if count % 10 == 1:
            print("Turning cursor off")
            lcd.hide_cursor()
        if count % 10 == 2:
            print("Turning blink cursor on")
            lcd.blink_cursor_on()
        if count % 10 == 3:
            print("Turning blink cursor off")
            lcd.blink_cursor_off()                    
        if count % 10 == 4:
            print("Turning backlight off")
            lcd.backlight_off()
        if count % 10 == 5:
            print("Turning backlight on")
            lcd.backlight_on()
        if count % 10 == 6:
            print("Turning display off")
            lcd.display_off()
        if count % 10 == 7:
            print("Turning display on")
            lcd.display_on()
        if count % 10 == 8:
            print("Filling display")
            lcd.clear()
            string = ""
            for x in range(32, 32+I2C_NUM_ROWS*I2C_NUM_COLS):
                string += chr(x)
            lcd.putstr(string)
        count += 1
        utime.sleep(2)
#if name == "main":
test_main()`

And, please give your answer in simple words. Thanks!

Schematic:

[image: How I wired it up]

I believe the problem has to do with contrast

Comment: the question should stand on its own without the need to access an external link, which may become invalid ... please add all information to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was to scew the pentiometer. Thanks anyway for trying to help me! :)